# Why does the searchbar cause the text to change fonts?

Tags: uitableview, fonts, searchbar

I have a uitableview with a searchbar as the header.  when I search, the font in my table switches to the ipad default font instead of Cochin, which is the one that it was and still should be when the table is searching.

I have the following code in my willDisplayCell: method.  And it is reached - I know because I put an NSLog by it, and the line prints.

```
UILabel *tempLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
tempLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin" size:17];
```

So why, when I press the searchbar, does the text change fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry.  I figured it out... I had been searching for the solution for a couple of hours and gave up and turned to stackoverflow 2 minutes before the miracle...

Despite having a custom cell with a tag to the uilabel, I was assigning the text to cell.textLabel.text = @"blah blah";

When I assigned the text to the tagged label, all was well.  Sorry and thanks!